# why am I being unable to access public array of a class inside other class?

Tags: c#, unity

I know this question has been asked before but my case is different(or i could not gather any kind of help from those)

I am facing "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" Error

in Class 1 I tried to make an array of a Class2 type and that class2 had two arrays of type "int"

but when i am filling up values in those arrays of Class2, by making object of Class2. it seems to be null.

well right now its not a problem but when i will use those value in other place it will create one. so i would really like to solve this right now.

PS:-
At first I used to fill those value by inspector plane in unity.
but now i want to fill them up by programatically at runtime

**Class1 Code**

```
public class LevelStructure : MonoBehaviour 
{
public static LevelStructure instance;

public int numberOfColumns=5;
public int numberOfRows=5;
internal ColumnStructure[] columnStructures;

int[] tilemap = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
int[] jellymap = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
void Awake()
{
    instance = this;
    //numberOfColumns = transform.GetChildCount();
    //columnStructures = transform.GetComponentsInChildren<ColumnStructure>();

    // I added the below code to put values at runtime programatically.
    // before that i used to put those from unity inspector plane.
    for (int i = 0; i<numberOfColumns; i++) 
    {

        ColumnStructure cs = new ColumnStructure();

        for(int j = 0; j<numberOfRows; j++)
        {

            if(cs==null)
            {
                Debug.Log("CS is null");

            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("CS is not null "+j);
                cs.itemAvailability[j] = (int)tilemap[i*numberOfColumns+j]; //This line is getting null reference exception
                cs.jelly[j] = (int)jellymap[i*numberOfColumns+j];

            }

        }
        columnStructures[i] = cs;

    }

}



}
```

**Class2 Code :-**

```
public class ColumnStructure 
{

public int[] itemAvailability;
public int[] jelly;

}
```

**Console Log :-**

```
CS is not null 0
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
LevelStructure:Awake() (at Assets/CM3/Scripts/Game Scripts/LevelStructure.cs:35)

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
LevelStructure.Awake () (at Assets/CM3/Scripts/Game Scripts/LevelStructure.cs:36)
```

ANSWER :-

Thanks to Petr Abdulin, I modified Class2 Code like this.

```
public class ColumnStructure 
{

public int[] itemAvailability = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
public int[] jelly = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
void Awake()
{

}
}
```

Comment: `cs` isn't null, but `cs.itemAvailability` is. Looks like you never populated that array.

Comment: @rutter : doesn't this statement cs.itemAvailability[j] = (int)tilemap[i*numberOfColumns+j]; count as populating the array ? if not  then how should i achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, from you code I see that in line:

```
cs.itemAvailability[j] = (int)tilemap[i*numberOfColumns+j];
```

`cs.itemAvailability` is definitely `null`. You declare an array variable but it's never initialized.

You need something like

```
cs.itemAvailability = new int[size_of_array];
```

if you want it to be an initialized array.